# Blender Motion tracking how to?

Tags: camera, motion-capture

I have two videos from different views one moving one steady. I am trying to track character movements for animations. I tried doing just a steady video but there was no depth or rotation. So I figured why not use two cameras one moving so I can track the camera and then I can use depth but I do not know exactly how to get the character rotations all the markers are the same and some go out of seen I had about 40 on me but how do I turn them into empties on a track? I know how to do everything else after that I just want the character trackers to have depth and rotations. I kinda thought about making my own constellation tracking system but I do not know how to implement it into blender and constellations could get expensive.